# Почему важно записывать ключи команд в определенной последовательности?

Tags: linux, консоль

Почему важно записывать ключи команд(в терминале linux) в определенной последовательности и существуют ли какие-то правила для этого?

Comment: нет, нет такого правила. Но некоторые программы требуют такого. И для этого стоит читать их документацию

Comment: спасибо за информацию, учту

Comment: но вполне возможно, что Вы столкнулись с какой то определенной командой. В этом случае лучше просто сказать о ней. Но вот приведу пример сам `cat file1 file2` и `cat file2 file1` - вот тут порядок очень важен - будет разный вывод.

Comment: а влияет ли использование полных названий ключей на последовательность расстановки(извиняюсь, если глупый вопрос); к данному вопросу я пришел при изучении команды tar, возможно вы можете сказать о какой-то особенности расставления ключей при использовании данной команды(возможно немного нагло, но все же)

Comment: практически всегда длинный ключ эквивалентен короткому. я не встречал, когда это может быть по другому, но допускаю такую возможность. команда tar достаточно старая и у нее осталось "для совместимости со старыми пользователями" много старых форматов. Там как минимум есть три разных способа - традиционный, юникс и гну. Они хоть и похожи, но чуточку по разному. И смешивать их точно не стоит

Comment: спасибо большое, буду знать

Comment: @KoVadim некоторые требования относительно порядка аргументов всё-таки [накладываются стандартом](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)

Comment: расскажите это dd:)